# Fixing TypeScript or lint setup to receive useful error messages

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings, tsconfig

IDE: WebStorm

I'm trying to figure out the reason why in two projects of mine, error messages related to type issues are different. On the left side, in my new project (A), they are presented differently and with a pretty impractical error message, while on the right side (B), it's what I would like to have.

Difference between A and B:
[image: difference between A and B]

Project A (not what I want):
[image: A - not useful]

Project B (what I want):
[image: B - useful]

Not being an expert in this, I guess the reasons can range from differences in `tsconfig.json`, `.eslintrc.json` to having installed different supporting libraries. But I don't really know where to start that debugging process so before pasting a lot of code, I may need some hints.

Some differences still:

Project A (not working):

- TypeScript 5.0.4
- tsconfig compiler options:

  ```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    ...
  }
  ```

Project B (working):

- TypeScript 4.8.4
- tsconfig compiler options:

  ```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "jsx": "react",
    ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Typescript 4.9.5 fixed the issue. I guess some other dependencies or idea settings are not working as expected yet with TS version 5.